# Match exact string and returns only that line in UNIX

Tags: unix

I'm looking to match only a particular string on a file and returns only that line.
for eg, my matching pattern is `/gp/digital/fiona/payment-checkout` if I grep this one I'm getting all 4 lines as below,

```
/gp/digital/fiona/payment-checkout/img/logo.svg<br>
/gp/digital/fiona/payment-checkout/undefined<br>
/gp/digital/fiona/payment-checkout/uedata/nvp/unsticky<br>
/gp/digital/fiona/payment-checkout
```

But I want only the line which contains `/gp/digital/fiona/payment-checkout`. 
I tried `grep -o -P -w` everything.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -x /gp/digital/fiona/payment-checkout file
/gp/digital/fiona/payment-checkout
```

`man grep`:

```
 -x, --line-regexp
              Select only those matches that exactly match the whole  line.   For  
              a  regular  expression  pattern,  this  is  like parenthesizing the 
              pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $
```

Using awk:

```
$ awk '$0=="/gp/digital/fiona/payment-checkout"' file
/gp/digital/fiona/payment-checkout
```